# Email:Pass regex for Preg_Match_All

Tags: php, regex, email

I have the following regex which grabs any IP:PORT:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3}:(\d){1,5}/ism',$page,$proxies);
```

That in which grabs all IP:PORTS from a specified page.
I need a way in which to grab Email:Pass from a specified page.
I don't want those Email Validators everywhere on here and I want it formatted somewhat like my IP:PORT's regex.

So it shouldnt grab:

```
Email.co.uk:P@ass
Email:Pass
etc.
```

It should grab:

```
Email@Email.co.uk:Pass123
etc.
```

Any help? Thx!

EDIT: it should also look for .coms and .co.uk's etc

Comment: Ill try and i need it in preg_match_replace but I get where u going with this but whats the # .. +#msi all about?

Comment: Dat wont work anyway as its searching for literally Email what im going to be regexing wont exactly be Email@whatever etc it will be like awesome@gmail.com e.t.c

Comment: Again its the same with the Pass bit :P and can you format it for preg match all plz wihtouth the weird # etc

Comment: Oh actually thx dude! Edited a slight bit of your regex and got this preg_match_all('/^[a-z0-9_.+-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-.]+:[a-z0-9-.]+/ism',$page,$accounts); works perfect!

Comment: All i needa do now is try and get my file_put contents to stop deleting whatever was matched last time it was used. :/ wont be hard at all thx dude!

Comment: I have posted that as an answer since it finally worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since my suggestion worked out for you, let me post it as an answer.

The regex you can use is

```
preg_match_all('/^[a-z0-9_.+-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-.]+:[a-z0-9-.]+/im',$page,$‌​accounts);
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eA6pU3/2)

Mind you do not need the `s` flag since there is no `.` (match any character) symbol in your pattern.

The regex is matching

- `^` - Beginning of a string
- `[a-z0-9_.+-]+` - 1 or more characters from the character class
- `@` - The @ symbol
- `[a-z0-9-]+` - 1 or more characters from the character class
- `\.` - A literal dot
- `[a-z0-9-.]+` - 1 or more characters from the character class
- `:` - A literal colon
- `[a-z0-9-.]+` - 1 or more characters from the character class

`/im` means "ignore case" (`i`) (so we do not have to use `[A-Z]` in our regex, `[a-z]` will suffice), and "multiline" (`m`) (so that `^` and `$` match a line start/end).

PS: Sorry for deleting my comments. I was using `#` as delimiters, and it is a totally valid regex delimiter in PHP.